# Why does setting the mem parameter on boot reduce the amount of addressable RAM by so much?

Tags: linux, bootloader

Due to some issues with modules, on boot I have to set mem=4096M. When this happens, though, this is the available memory:

MemTotal:  3354504 kB
SwapTotal: 1670724 kB

as opposed to

MemTotal:  4057728 kB
SwapTotal: 1670724 kB

Why is the amount of RAM dropping so much? Shouldn't it just stay at 4057728kB or pretend to have more?

Answer (score 1):

Memory-mapped I/O such as that for video, sound, disks, etc. takes a certain number of physical addresses. Normally the RAM behind it is mapped somewhere else, but since you've artificially limited the number of physical addresses available to the OS there is no way for the OS to actually *reach* this RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: As a follow up question, Linux can still see the swap area. Does it every get used seeing as how it can only address 3.2 MB of RAM?

Comment: The *system* sees 3.2GB of RAM, but each process still gets 2/3/4GB of virtual memory, any of which could be backed by swap.

Comment: Thanks. Will the extra RAM be used as a sort of swap space as well?

Comment: The extra RAM can only be used by kernel modules that explicitly map into its space (of which I know of none). It is not available to processes in any other way.